# What is the correct alternative to using ListViews in a NestedScrollView?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-scrollview

I'm creating a detail view for a Dictionary entry. The basic structure is as follows: A dictionary item can have 1 or many 'Meanings'. Each of these 'Meanings' can further have 0 or many 'Field of Applications', 'Part of Speech', and 'Dialect' values. There are other similar sections for a dictionary item as well such as example sentences.

Due to the size and structure varying based on a query result, it seems to me like the best way to do this would be to have multiple ListViews as follows:

[image: Detail view components mockup]

**I realise that putting ListViews inside ScrollViews is a bad idea**, and [Google themselves](https://plus.google.com/+AdamWPowell/posts/T5AgJ7jiK88) say you shouldn't do it, so what is the 'best practice' way to accomplish something like this?

I've thought of the following solutions, none of which seem ideal:

1. Use a single TextView instead of a ListView, and use new line characters to separate data rows. This feels very hacky and makes formatting specific parts of a row difficult.
2. Replace the ListViews with LinearLayouts, then programmatically insert TextViews within them as needed.
3. Create a custom ListView which is not scrollable.

This seems like a very common use case for a detail view, yet I can't find any concrete answer on how to deal with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace your ListView with RecyclerView (and adapter as well= and call

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

which will enable smooth nested scrolling.

Comment: but thats not a good idea to use `ListView` inside `nested scroll view`

Comment: @Paras why not? It's exactly why Google invented NestedScrollView

Comment: yeah my bad.. I got confused with normal scroll view.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this seems to be what I'm looking for. Would you recommend using a single RecyclerView with varying item types and section headers or multiple RecyclerViews for each section?

Comment: @LukeCasey yeah, I think performance would be better by using single RV and deal properly with headers and item types. maybe look at Epoxy library if you're free to use 3rd party software

Comment: Just wanted to say I got it working with a RecyclerView inside my NestedScrollView and it works great! Thanks again.

Comment: No problem! Glad i helped.